# Group adapter items

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

i need to create a custom adapter for address book, grouping them by first name letter inside a custom layout. How can i achive a result like this?
[image]

I created an `Hashmap<String firstLetter,Arraylist<Contacts>>` but i dunno how to pass it to an adapter to make **EACH SINGLE ELEMENT OF THE LIST** clickable.

Best solution i've found up to now is to inflate as many ListView for each letter of my HashMap, and setting the adapter to it

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, ArrayList<RlyJiffyContact>> entry : contactLinkedHashMap.entrySet()) {
        Character key = entry.getKey();
        ArrayList<RlyJiffyContact> value = entry.getValue();
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            LinearLayoutWithLabel llbel = new LinearLayoutWithLabel(getContext());
            llbel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            llbel.setPadding(R.dimen.default_margin_left, R.dimen.default_margin_top, R.dimen.default_margin_right, R.dimen.default_margin_bottom);
            llbel.setText(key.toString().toUpperCase());
            ListView list = new ListView(getContext());
            list.setAdapter(new RlyJiffyContactsAdapter(getContext(), value));
            llbel.addView(list);
            linear.addView(llbel);
        }
```

and the adapter

```
public class MYADAPTER extends ArrayAdapter<MYELEMENT> {

LayoutInflater vi;
private Context               context;
private List<RlyJiffyContact> contacts;
public MYADAPTER(Context context, List<MYELEMENT> contacts) {
    super(context, 0, contacts);
    vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.contacts = contacts;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderItem holderItem;
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holderItem = new ViewHolderItem();

        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.reply_jiffy_contact_line, null);
        holderItem.contactNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_number);
        holderItem.displayName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_display_name);
        holderItem.preferedImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_prefered);
        convertView.setTag(holderItem);
    } else {
        holderItem = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    RlyJiffyContact item = getItem(position);
    holderItem.contactNumber.setText(item.getPhoneNumber());
    holderItem.displayName.setText(item.getName() + " " + item.getSurname());
    if (item.isPrefered()) {
        holderItem.preferedImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holderItem.preferedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new ContactPhoneListener(item.getPhoneNumber()));
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView  contactNumber;
    TextView  displayName;
    ImageView preferedImage;

}
private class ContactPhoneListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String number;
    public ContactPhoneListener(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), FIRSTACTIVITY.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.CONTACT_IDENTIFIER, number);
        i.setAction(Constants.SENDING_CONTACT);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

But the result is that i can see only first element for each letter(
EXAMPLE:

my contacts:

- Anne a
- Anne B
- anthony c
- Bob a
- Bob b
- Bob c

what i see in my list

1. Anne a
2. Bob a

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this type of list  :
Use a ArrayList of type Char or String,
in the getView() method get the first letter of the name by name.chatAt(0).toUpperCase();
in if condition if the array contains the first character of the name then just return the normal view from the getview method, otherwise add the character in array and create a simple textview and set the character on the textview and return the textview from the getview method.

try this..

Comment: not understanding what are you suggesting me. Can you provide a sample of code that u would implement?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a Rolodex adapter of which there are two variants, found [here](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters). There's also demo app there with plenty of example code. As their name implies, its design to handle circumstances where data is arranged from itself. In your case, the first letter of each name.  It'll automatically sort your list of names under the appropriate grouping for you.  It works with an `ExpandableListView` and allows you to specify if the children and groupings are clickable. Default is clickable.  If you don't need filtering capabilities, I suggest you specifically use the `NFRolodexArrayAdapter`.  Here's a simple example:

**The Activity/Fragment**

```
//There's no need to pre-compute what the groupings are for each contact. Just pass in your List of contacts as is. 
PeopleAdapter adapter = new PeopleAdapter (this, mContacts);
mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Adapter**

```
class PeopleAdapter extends NFRolodexArrayAdapter<String, Contacts> {

    PeopleAdapter(Context activity, Collection<Contacts> items) {
        super(activity, items);
    }

    @Override
    public String createGroupFor(Contacts childItem) {
        //This is how the adapter determines what the groupins are and what contact belongs to it
        return childItem.getFirstLetterOfFirstName();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(LayoutInflater inflater, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate your view

        //Gets the Contact data for this view
        Contacts contact = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        //Fill view with contact data
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(LayoutInflater inflater, int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate your group view

        //Gets the Letter for this view
        String letter = getGroup(groupPosition);

        //Fill view with letter
    }
}
```